# Want to send email template through custom button click in magento2

Tags: magento2

I have created a custom button on sale order view. Now want to send an customized email template through that button click.in magento2. please help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

How to send email in Magento 2

1. Declare your email template
   To declare a custom email template that goes with your extension, create the file /etc/email_templates.xml.

In our example: Magenest/AbandonedCart/etc/email_templates.xml

Sample Code:

```
<config 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="abandonedcart_item1"
              label="Abandoned Cart Item 1"
              file="abandonedcart_item1.html"
              type="html"
              module="Magenest_AbandonedCart"
              area="frontend"
    />
</config>
```

A detailed answer can be found [here](https://store.magenest.com/blog/how-to-send-email-in-magento-2/).

Comment: I  am using this but when I am calling helper in controller it is giving constroctor error. please help

Comment: This error indicates you are initializing wrong or missing constructor in controller. If you just share your code maybe I can help you

Comment: Thanks. your suggestion help me alot.